# Create Token Account only if not Initialized yet in program (Native Rust)

Tags: rust, token, program

Doing this in Typescript is pretty straightforward by making an RPC call or `getOrCreateAssociatedAccount`, but I am wondering if there is a way to do this program side as well without using Anchor.

For example, say I want my program to mint some tokens to a user - but I'll also want the program to create the token account if it does not already exist before minting. Does this check have to be handled on the client side or can I implement the program side as well?

Comment: **in anchor** add `init_if_needed` constraint Exact same functionality as the `init` constraint but only runs if the account does `not exist yet`.
If the account does exist, it still checks whether the given init constraints are correct, e.g. that the account has the expected amount of space and, if it's a PDA, the correct seeds etc. ``` #[account(init_if_needed, payer = payer)] pub data_account: Account<'info, MyData>,
``` --- **note** This feature should be used with care and is therefore behind a feature flag. You can enable it by importing anchor-lang with the init-if-needed cargo feature.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I should have clarified though I was looking for a way to do this in Native Rust (i.e. without Anchor)

Comment: Although I really advise you that you use Anchor since it saves you a lot of time, you can either check init_if_needed in the anchor lang repo and try to do the same, or you can check the data if allocated then only initialize if it's empty (just throwing ideas)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you need the target associated token account for *something* in your program already - like to transfer to it - you can just conditionally create it if it doesn't exist.

The logic looks like this, but note you'd want to coordinate who signs/pays for this account creation, and it's not usually advisable to have unpredictable rent-paying in a program's instruction.

```
if to_associated_token_account.lamports() == 0 {
    msg!("Creating associated token account for recipient...");
    invoke(
        &associated_token_account_instruction::create_associated_token_account(
            payer.key,
            recipient.key,
            mint_account.key,
            token_program.key,
        ),
        &[
            mint_account.clone(),
            to_associated_token_account.clone(),
            recipient.clone(),
            payer.clone(),
            system_program.clone(),
            token_program.clone(),
            associated_token_program.clone(),
        ],
    )?;
} else {
    msg!("Associated token account exists.");
}
```