# Looking for implementation example of anchor_spl::token::initialize_account

Tags: anchor, solana-program, spl-token, anchor-spl, spl-associated-token-account

I want to use the initialize_account function from anchor_spl::token.

The function is given below:

```
pub fn initialize_account<'a, 'b, 'c, 'info>(
    ctx: CpiContext<'a, 'b, 'c, 'info, InitializeAccount<'info>>
) -> Result<()>
```

The struct is:

```
pub struct InitializeAccount<'info> {
    pub account: AccountInfo<'info>,
    pub mint: AccountInfo<'info>,
    pub authority: AccountInfo<'info>,
    pub rent: AccountInfo<'info>,
}
```

I am confused about implementing this in my anchor smart contract. Particularly, I want to know what is the account in the struct. An example implementation would be really helpful since it is not available online

Answer (score 4):

The `initialize_account` function is to create a new Token Account.

The `account` in the struct is the Token Account that is being initialized in the instruction

Here's a solpg link for reference implementation:
https://beta.solpg.io/63170ee1bb7e0b5f4ca6df9c

```
#[program]
mod hello_anchor {
    use super::*;
    pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<Initialize>) -> Result<()> {
        let space = anchor_spl::token::TokenAccount::LEN as u64;
        let lamports = Rent::get()?.minimum_balance(space as usize);
        
        let ix = anchor_lang::solana_program::system_instruction::create_account(
            &ctx.accounts.authority.key(),
            &ctx.accounts.token_account.key(),
            lamports,
            space,
            &anchor_spl::token::ID,
        );

        anchor_lang::solana_program::program::invoke(
            &ix,
            &[ctx.accounts.authority.to_account_info(), ctx.accounts.token_account.to_account_info(), ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info()])?;
        
        let cpi_program = ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info();
        let cpi_accounts = InitializeAccount {
            account: ctx.accounts.token_account.to_account_info(),
            mint: ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
            authority: ctx.accounts.authority.to_account_info(),
            rent: ctx.accounts.rent.to_account_info(),
        };
        let cpi_ctx = CpiContext::new(cpi_program, cpi_accounts);
        anchor_spl::token::initialize_account(cpi_ctx)?;
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub token_account: Signer<'info>,
    pub mint: Account<'info, Mint>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub authority: Signer<'info>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    pub rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to create token account with same address as when created by default?

Comment: if I donot input a random pubkey for token_account it displays an error

Comment: by default, do you mean the associated token account?

Comment: yes the default ATA which is created by doing CLI command

Comment: https://docs.rs/anchor-spl/latest/anchor_spl/associated_token/struct.Create.html

Comment: https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/2298/create-token-account-only-if-not-initialized-yet-in-program-native-rust/2300#2300

Comment: here's a Solpg example using init_if_needed: https://beta.solpg.io/6317c4d1bb7e0b5f4ca6dfa2

Answer (score 3):

Here's a Solpg example for how to create an associated token account in Anchor using `init_if_needed`

https://beta.solpg.io/6317c4d1bb7e0b5f4ca6dfa2

```
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use anchor_spl::associated_token::AssociatedToken;
use anchor_spl::token::{Mint, Token, TokenAccount};

declare_id!("GAvTLLgVwq7iTk7WCA4Nr2nmtoHGK8E6VWAoZHi4k32X");

#[program]
mod hello_anchor {
    use super::*;
    pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<Initialize>) -> Result<()> {
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
    #[account(
        init_if_needed,
        payer = payer, 
        associated_token::mint = mint, 
        associated_token::authority = payer
    )]
    pub token_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
    pub mint: Account<'info, Mint>,
     #[account(mut)]
    pub payer: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    pub associated_token_program: Program<'info, AssociatedToken>,
    pub rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,
}
```

[image]